# Vuejs select options

Tags: vue.js, dynamically-generated

Trying to make select option:

- DVD
- Books
- Furniture

When selecting `DVD` it changes the element content to:

[image: DVD selection content].

Code on select option and the form that should change:

```html
<div class="typeswitcher">
                <div>
                    <h4 class="typeHeading">Type Switcher</h4>
                </div>
                <select name="typeSwitcher" id="typeSwitcher" v-model="itemType">
                    <option value="DVD" id="DVD" >DVD</option>
                    <option value="dimensions" id="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                    <option value="weight" id="Book">Books</option>
                    
                </select>
            </div>
            <form method="POST">
                    <div class="switcher-form">
                        <!-- //slice used to remove unnecessary iterations from the v-for -->
                        <div v-if="itemType === 'DVD'" class="row mb-1" v-html="item.size" v-for="item in switcherForm.slice(0,1)":key="item" >
                        </div>
                        <div v-if="itemType === 'dimensions'" class="row mb-1"v-html="item.dimensions" v-for="item in switcherForm.slice(1,2)":key="item">                            
                        </div>
                        <div v-if="itemType === 'weight'" class="row mb-1" v-html="item.weight" v-for="item in switcherForm.slice(2,3)":key="item" >
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
```

```js
import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'

    createApp({
        data() {
        return {
            title: 'Add product',
            itemType:null,
            switcherForm: [
                            {size:`
                            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Size (MB)</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input id="size" type="text" name="size" placeholder="size" value="<?php echo $size; ?>"></input>
                                <h6>Please provide DVD size in MB.</h6>
                            </div>
                            `},
                            {dimensions:`
                            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Dimensions</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="dimensions" placeholder="dimensions" value="<?php echo $dimensions; ?>"></input>
                                <h6>Please provide dimensions in HxWxL. format</h6>
                            </div>
                            `},
                            {weight:`
                             <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Weight (KG)</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="weight" value="<?php echo $weight; ?>"></input>
                                <h6>Please provide Book weight in KG.</h6>
                            </div>
                            `},
    
                        ] 
            }
        },
    }).mount('#add-product')
```

I got it working like this, connected the `itemType:null` to typeswitcher with v-model and then used

```html
<div v-if="itemType === 'DVD'" class="row mb-1" v-html="item.size" v-for="item in switcherForm.slice(0,1)":key="item" >
```

with every input I wanted to render.
Used `slice` method to cut off excess `v-for` iterations. `switcherForm` is an array of objects with the html inputs.

[Here's a minimal working example](https://codepen.io/aTHEM2/pen/gOezQJr)

Comment: Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS vulnerabilities. Only use `v-html` on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

Comment: Thank you for answer. What could be safer way to render my input? Like rendering in the html straight away and using show and hide with some condition?

Comment: if it's only text, use `v-text` instead. i took the information from here - https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-text and here - https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html

Comment: and could u write a reproducible example of your issue? will be easier to help

Comment: i added codepen maby this helps to see the page better what i want to change when switching between the typeswitcher

Comment: at the moment i got it to work like i wanted , its in the codepen , but im still using the v-html i wonder how can i replace it so its secure.

Comment: another thing is that you shouldn't be mixing php and vue - `<input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="weight" value="<?php echo $weight; ?>"></input>` - don't. instead, somehow you should be passing the props from your backend to the frontend

Comment: hmm at the moment i have assignment to make this page with BE php and using vuejs as front is bonus if i can do it . Better to do front also with php then ?

Comment: if it's just an assignment i guess u can do it like that, but in a real project, dont mix php with vue in a html file. instead use php as backend and pass in props to vue components. if u go into laravel u'll learn it